# How to get hg mdiff to ignore whitespace differences?

Tags: mercurial, diff, whitespace, development-environment, utility

I recently started using mercurial. I often want to check differences between revisions while ignoring whitespace (e.g. due to running `dos2unix` on certain files). Now, for `hg mdiff`, I can do this using a  modified diff command, `hg wdiff`, the arrangement of which is described here:

[Whitespace-ignoring diffs with Mercurial](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/bz/archives/2009/08/whitespaceignoring_diffs_with.html)

How can I do the same for `hg mdiff`?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't. The `Mergediff` extension has a very different implementation, that's likely not supported by command-line diff tools (if only because it has to compare 3 versions instead of just 2).

You could extend the Mergediff extension to have a whitespace-ignoring mode, I guess.